# Why do I get two icons in lower panel for each application running?

Tags: 11.04

I just upgraded to 12.04.  Now I get two icons in the lower gnome panel for every application that's open. I am using gnome without effects.
The problem started when I switched from a two monitor configuration to a single monitor configuration. ( I disabled the internal graphic output of my laptop with the nvidia-settings program )

Comment: Can you put a screenshot?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).